# HLSL Render To Texture / Stream Output in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, gpgpu, hlsl

I am trying to implement an HLSL Shader in Unity 5 which displaces the vertices of a sphere.

What I'm trying to work out is how do I effectively pass information from one frame to the next so that I can 'save' the calculated velocities of each vertex.

On an [Nvidia dev site](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/all/modules/custom/gpugems/books/GPUGems/gpugems_ch38.html) I found an interesting article discussing GPU fluid dynamics simulations. In that article, they state:

> On the GPU, though, the output of fragment processors is always written to the frame buffer. Think of the frame buffer as a two-dimensional array that cannot be directly read. There are two ways to get the contents of the frame buffer into a texture that can be read:
>
> - Copy to texture (CTT) copies from the frame buffer to a texture.
> - Render to texture (RTT) uses a texture as the frame buffer so the GPU can write directly to it.

I remember reading (source lost) that in Unity, the `RenderTexture` is an FBO, but after hours of searching, I still don't understand how to implement this (if this even is the correct way to achieve this). My current thought was that I would create 2 passes, one to calculate the new velocities from the existing velocities and then a second to manipulate the mesh.

I've considered writing a GPGPU Shader, but I desperately want all of this functionality contained within a single Shader.

I'm at a dead end, can someone please just point me in the right direction.

**Clarification:**

In a `Unity Compute Shader` I can render / output whatever I want to a render texture(s):

> Render Textures can also be written into from compute shaders, if they have “random access” flag set (“unordered access view” in DX11), see RenderTexture.enableRandomWrite.
> http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ComputeShaders.html

Also note:

> DirectX10 introduced a new feature known as Stream Output that is very useful for implementing particle systems. OpenGL followed in version 3.0 with the same feature and named it Transform Feedback. http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial28/tutorial28.html

Can I do this in a **normal shader**? Is there a **stream output** in Unity 5.1+. Is there a transform feedback option?

Comment: I happy to help you, but you have no concrete questions. Could you please post code what you have? or split your question to several questions? Good question is half of success.

Comment: @Unick please see clarification.